# Who's responsibility to call $http? Service or Controller?

Tags: angularjs, http, model-view-controller, architecture

As a backend developer I am little bit struggling with **Angular UI MVC** concept.

I am trying to draw parallels to my backend MVC so I can understand mindset behind Angular better.

On my backend I have services talking to repositories(or DAOs (**D**ata **A**ccess **O**bjects) how we called them in past), controllers calling services to do the job(as they only transport data and not do heavy lifting) and talk to the client(ie browser) and my Model is a combo of(DTOs (**D**ata **T**ransfer **O**bjects) and Entities as of ORM).

As I am inherently inspired by having backend only ever to return/accept JSON(big no to JSP,FreeMarker,Velocity and all others which make my testing life so hard). I would say that on my backend I only have *Model-Controller*. From the backend perspective my *View* is AngularJS as JSON data I return could be labelled as part of my *Model* but it is definitely not my *View*.

Now when I start to think about UI MVC as of AngularJS **I don't understand who should use $http service to talk to backend**. The endless examples scattered across the web do not help me. They are either too minimalist or don't show the usage of $http in the full context(simply called from controllers).

I could argue easily for both.

**Case A:** If AngularJS treats backend as *Model* then it is the responsibility of angular's services to call $http to talk to backend to retrieve/post data. Here angular controllers still act as basic transport between *View* and *Model* ocassionally calling services to get and process data from backend.

**Case B**
I could also say, hold on - "no", if angular's controllers role is solely to transport then they should get data from backend and deliver to required destination i.e. angular's service/view(if no further processing required).

So which one is "right"? Or at least widely accepted by UI/fullstack devs?

Comment: raising the flag as m59 was downvoted 2 times for first correct and precise answer. I accepted his answer and my question from 2 upvotes dropped to -1. How SO even works..

Please verify that tucker and tyler were not involved in downvoting. Cause SO sometimes has weird appraisal outcomes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers should only be connecting data and logic with the view and in the most minimal way possible. A bulky controller suggests that either the view needs to be divided up or logic needs to be abstracted into services. `$http` calls definitely belong in services. The controller doesn't care how the data comes, just that it comes. So:

```
// controller doesn't care how
getData().then(function(data) {
```

VS:

```
// controller is too concerned with "how"
$http.get('/the/path').then(function(data) {
```

It is typical to see `$http` calls in controllers in sample code, but not in professional production code.

Comment: ahh got it wrong :-), no worries, will have to move then my code. Not sure about localStorageService the plugin LocalStorageModule. In this case I guess it is more flexible(as no details how to get or set). Can be called directly from controller?

Comment: @Aubergine I wouldn't know without seeing the situation. It's just a guideline to try to follow anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest Case A: having this in a service.

Think of Angular controllers as owning each specific piece of view they are assigned to, with services providing ready-made functionality for those controllers.

Also note that a single page can have many views, each of which could be bound to its own instance of a given controller.  So it doesn't really make sense to have `$http`-based functions etc being instantiated a bunch of times.  For a service, it will be instantiated once and then shared across any controller that injects it.  This is also a great way to share data between controllers, and is one of the strongest reasons to use a service for any given task.

Comment: `$http` wouldn't be instantiated multiple times. Services are singletons. They are instantiated once, which is the first time they are injected.

Comment: You're right, what I meant was `$http`-based functions.  I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

One other suggestion is that thinking of Angular as MVC can lead to issues. Angular is flexible enough to follow multiple design patterns, hence the MVW (Model View Whatever) moniker, but the majority of applications I have seen tend to follow the MVVM pattern. For this reason I would say that the controller should never have knowledge of $http in most cases.